# How do I disable javelin jsp-recompiler in weblogic 10.3?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x

How do I disable weblogic's javelin recompiler? It seems to be using some version of JDK5 source level, and I believe that this can be disabled in weblogic 10 in favor of regular JDK6.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: That's weird, WSL 10.3 shouldn't be using javelin AFAIK :-S

Comment: I'm on Oracle support now, so hopefully I can get a good answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weblogic's support structure is horrible. There is no solution.